# "Ask Question" button in different position for meta than main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, asking, mothership

I realise how trivial this is, but given how meta Arqade and Arqade seem graphically alike in every respect (apart from the grayscale,) it seems strange that the Ask Question button is in a different position.

[image]

[image]

Also, it would be nice to have the same animation as the button on the main site for the button on meta.

Comment: +1 for META LAZERS. (I couldn't care less about the tiny misalignment though. But that's just me.)

Comment: Sure, it's no biggie, just figured it was worth mentioning. I agree that lasers are more important any day :').

Comment: See also: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/make-the-meta-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Stack Exchange's move to a standardized site design, this issue has been solved (albeit inadvertently). The 'Ask Question' button has been moved:

[image: Ask Question - Main Site]

[image: Ask Question - Meta Site]

and the mothership now aligns properly:

[image: Mothership - Main Site]

[image: Mothership - Meta Site]

Don't mind the horrible cropping on my part - the button and mothership ARE actually aligned. :)