# "Ask question" button position

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, asking

I am using [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) most of time.

Today I struggle for a few minutes (!) when wanted to ask a question at Arqade.

The reason was: **I couldn't find the button to ask a new question**.

Should we do something about it or you think it's not a problem?

---

This is how it looks at SO:

[image]

And at Arqade (meta is nearly the same):

[image]

My eyes were looking for a button at the upper right corner (which is correct), but my brains were limiting the screen to the white rectangle and the button suddenly "gone".

Another point is that button is *barely* visible: blue on blue.

The "easiest" thing to fix the problem would be to move that button into rectangle and put it right next to the number of questions. There is free space anyway.

I also see there are other posts, e.g. one complaining what it's not [obviuosly a button](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/135338). The change I proposed will fix this issue too I believe.

Comment: SE is unifying the designs for all sites anyway, so there isn't much sense in changing this in the old design now. This could be taken into account in the new, unified design.

Comment: @MadScientist, didn't know about it, thanks. Do you have a link to such a post? That would be a perfect answer to my question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes/307866

Comment: This is a fair point, but most of have come to know and love the mothership. And its lazers. Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9742/ask-question-button-in-different-position-for-meta-than-main-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). The 'Ask Question' button has been changed to a standard button and moved to be more prominent:

[image: Ask Question - Main Site]

[image: Ask Question - Meta Site]

This was part of a broader push to [standardize site designs across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041). All of the SE network sites including Arqade have been updated with a new layout (and design changes to match).

Arqade's site design rollout was announced & discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182).