# Missing "Newest" button upon visiting arqade

Tags: discussion

I spotted a new design today and I like it [much more](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13007/135338).

If I arrive to site using direct link https://gaming.stackexchange.com or using "my community" item (preferred way for me, I prefer to have StackOverflow bookmarked and visit other StackExchange communities from it) then it shows active questions. And there is a missing button "Newest" which will only appears if I chose "Questions" from left navigation panel.

[image]

[image]

Before the change of design the button "New" was there and I could click it immediately. Now it's not and I have to additionally open side navigation and click something there.

Some observations:

Notice the address, clicking "Active" button on second screenshot will go to `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active` which shows both button too.

Is it a bug or a feature I don't understand? Can someone explain me why there are two different pages and why we need such a difference?

Answer (score 2):

The left nav change only moved everything (except for the badges tab) to the left sidebar, so it works the same as before (at least on this site, without having custom question lists enabled). You can verify how the old site worked by going to the [Archive.org saved copy of the old site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170915041443/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). The only difference is now the navigation hides from you if your window is too small or you change that preference. Everything is working as intended.

Anyway, here's an explanation of what's happening. There are three different lists of questions in the sidebar (Home, Questions, Unanswered), each of which have tabs. Home [filters out low scoring questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99932/323179), Unanswered only shows unanswered questions, and Questions isn't filtered. Therefore, even tabs with the same name (e.g. Home: active vs. Questions: active) show a different list of questions.

This is what the home page of the old site looked like. This is the page you arrive on when you navigated from "My Communities", or when you clicked on "Arqade" in the top left:

[image]

After you clicked on a question you probably thought you were returning to the same page, but you were probably going to the Questions page by clicking the green "Questions" tab. This tab is now in the sidebar. Here's a graphic visualizing how all the tabs moved:

[image]

It's all confusing, but you probably didn't realize you should be confused until now.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention how it was before. Last week when I chose `Arqade` in my communities list (I prefer to only bookmark StackOverlow and visit other communities from there), then Arqade site was opened with Active tab (maybe it was called differently, don't remember) and with New button, which I immediately click and enjoy. Now there is no New button and one way to go to that "New" list is to use left navigation panel, which is somewhat uncomfortable. My question is basically why there is no "New" button in first place? Why it was removed (compared to previous design)?

Comment: Please note: I didn't ask about left navigation panel, I prefer not to use it all. Ideally would be cool if every StackExchange site remember my "preferred" page to visit (when I choose community from list), because it will be "New" on all of them for me. But it's "Active" and with new design it's even more hassle (I mean click ^^) to reach "New", which I don't like.

Comment: So the statement *"so it works the same as before"* - isn't true.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm afraid I wasn't clear enough. Please see the added explanation, link to the old site, and images I added because I think it's a lot more clearer now.